# How do I pass an array to a postgresql where query?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a rather simple query, I just need to check that a row's primary key is in an array of integers.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id in [573240252177580032, 706271127542038608, 772980293929402389]
```

However, this yields the following error: 'syntax error near or at "["'

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ANY` function for that:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bdf18e62bf9890b521d6087e180eb1a8)

```
SELECT * 
FROM entries 
WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[573240252177580032, 706271127542038608, 772980293929402389])
```